# Subir una imagen y bajarle el peso sin disminuir calidad con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, archivo

Buenas tardes amigos mi código actualmente funciona muy bien, selecciono una imagen y esa imagen sube la ruta y el nombre de la imagen a la base de datos (la imagen se guarda en una carpeta).

El problema es que las imágenes que subo pesan muchos megas, quisiera optimizar este código para ver de que forma puedo seguir subiendo las imágenes de la misma forma solo que bajarle el peso de las imágenes al subirla.

Este es mi index.php

```
<h2>Foto</h2>


<form action="actualizar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="id_acta" value="<?php echo $datost['id_acta']?>">

<input type="text" name="foto_serie" value="<?php echo $datost['foto_serie']?>" readonly="readonly">


<td><?php function generarCodigo($longitud)
 { 
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890'; 
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1; 
    
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) 
        $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)
    }; 
    return $key; };?> 
    </td>

<td><input type="hidden" class="camp" name="enlace" value="S<?php echo generarCodigo(8);?>" readonly="readonly" style="width:200px;"></td>
    
</tr>

 <tr>
 <td></td>
<?php                                   
if(empty($fotoser))
{ 
?>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Sin foto</font></td>
<?php
}
else{ 
?>
<td><img src="<?php echo $datost['foto_serie']; ?>" width="200px"/></td>
<?php
}
?>  
 
 


Seleccione la nueva foto:
<input type="file" name="file_array" required>



   
<input type="submit" value="SUBIR IMAGEN"/>
      
</form>
```

Y este es el código de actualizar: aquí es donde se sube la foto o se actualiza dependiendo del caso.

```
<?php 
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "boom23140", "mainten3_kaltire");

$id_acta= $_POST['id_acta'];
$foto_serie= $_POST['foto_serie'];
$enlace=$_POST['enlace'];

$firmone=$_POST['firmone'];
$firmtwo=$_POST['firmtwo'];

     $ruta="".$foto_serie;
     unlink($ruta);

    
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    $lugar="actasf/".$enlace."_".$name_array;
    $lugar1="actasf/".$enlace."_".$name_array;
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array,$lugar);
          
          
    $sql1="update acta set foto_serie='$lugar1', firmone='".$firmone."', firmtwo='".$firmtwo."' where id_acta='$id_acta'";

    
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);

if($resultado){

     echo"<script type='text/javascript'>           
    
    swal({
        icon:  'success',
        title: 'Perfecto!',
        text:  'Actualizo correctamente la foto'
            }).then(function() {
                window.location = 'index.php?id_acta=$id_acta';
            });
        
        </script>"; 
}else{
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>            
    
    swal({
        icon:  'error',
        title: 'Oops!',
        text:  'El formato no es correcto, intente con JPG o PNG'
            }).then(function() {
                window.location = 'index.php?idusuario=$idusuario';
            });
        
        </script>";
}

?>
```

Todo funciona muy bien pero no tengo idea de como hacer para que al momento de subir la foto le baje peso, ejemplo si la foto pesa 40 megas que la baje por allí a 1 mega.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me sera de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Del lado de Javscript no es posible tal compresion de ratio. Solo del lado del código PHP podes comprimir, bajando la calidad de la imagen.

Comment: Una alternativa es utilizar la api canvas, podes comprimir recortando los pixeles del area de la imagen, y exportando a base64. luego del lado servidor php haces un decode base64 para obtener el binario original.